# Monitor Tomcat Webapp

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a Tomcat webapp running on Amazon EC2. I am expecting heavy usage of the webapp in the future and is therefore trying to understand how to monitor webapp and ensure it is   working well.

The Amazon EC2 shows the following *Cloudwatch Metrics* for each EC2 instance

1. Avg CPU Utilization
2. Avg Disk Reads
3. Sum Disk Read Ops (Count)
4. Avg Disk Writes
5. Sum Disk Writes Ops (Count)
6. Max Network Ins
7. Max Network Outs
8. Sum Status (Any)
9. Sum Status Instance
   10.Sum Status System

I have also found a library [Metrics](https://github.com/codahale/metrics), which can be used for monitoring JVM but I have not be able to understand the idea complete of what should I be monitoring and why?

**My Question**

What and why should be I monitoring to ensure my Tomcat Webapp works fine when sudden increase in user load on server?

Comment: Can you please provide more information if none of the answers below are correct, or accept one of the answers :)

Comment: @david99world I appreciate. The reason why I have not accepted the answer is because I have not been able to implement any of the suggested answers of now (but I plan to do so in the future, I am on it) and feels I should only accept the best solution so that future users can use it. Your suggestions/differences on my thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/).  It's a way of measuring the JVM that Tomcat runs on (you can analyse multiple Tomcat instances this way) using a web front end.  As well as the ability to see which classes are taking the most strain.

Of course as you've mentioned, you still get all the analysis provided by Amazon for your instances.

What you should be looking for is any classes which are taking a particularly large amount of usage and trying to optimize these processes.  VisualVM will give you statistics around this.

Comment: +1, Can you suggest some source of how to configure VisualVM for Tomcat 7 running in Amazon EC2?

Comment: Essentially the fact it's running on EC2 should be irrelevant, you can either install it on the instance itself, in which case you get by far more functionality - or do it remotely, I've personally never done it remotely simply because of the added functionality.  You can then look at the Tomcat instance.  Have a skim over http://visualvm.java.net/features.html try installing it locally on a JVM - I use it to debug JBoss locally :)  Bare in mind you are looking at the JVM, not just Tomcat.  But you can filter out jars in your project only.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running a GUI on your server, as they are fairly heavyweight. On the other hand, any remote JMX-based solution is a complete pain in the neck except for [JMXProxy[(http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet).

Answer (score 1):

What you have described in your *Cloudwatch Metrics* is **hardware** monitoring.

Monitoring Tomcat is what we call **software** monitoring. This involves (but is not limited to):

- user session count
- thread count
- various memory statistics (heap used/max, permgen used/max, old gen, eden sizes etc.)
- garbage collection (promotions between zones, frequency, full stop-the-world events, etc.)
- uptime
- your app-specific monitors (e.g. if you require database access, ability to do simple selects like `SELECT * FROM DUAL` which have negligible cost)

Why all these things? Each of them helps to better understand your apps bottlenecks and possible outages or slow response periods. Each of these metrics can explain why your app has suddenly stopped responding or response times have ballooned.

I also suggest you to look at [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) which is the standard interface for monitoring. You probably want to expose all these monitors via JMX.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) + [JMXProxy](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet) to instrument the JVM itself as well as a wealth of information exposed by Tomcat.

You can read some recommendations of what things to monitor on Tomcat's [Monitoring FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring).

It's amazing what you can find if you read documentation and FAQs.